# Lookup value in dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes - one is a main dataframe (main_df) and the other is a lookup dataframe (lookup_df). I have two conditions in the main dataframe that I need to use to look up a value in the lookup dataframe. My data is as follows:

main_df

```
Bore      Temperature
4            200
0.75         500
6            200
2            400
3            200
0.75         300
```

lookup_df

```
Bore      200      300      400      500
0.5       0.5      0.5      0.5      0.5
0.75      0.5      0.5      0.5      0.5
1         0.5      0.5      0.5      0.5
2         0.5      0.5      0.5      1.0
3         0.5      0.5      1.0      1.0
4         0.5      1.0      1.0      1.0
6         1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
```

My goal is to have a new column in the main_df that has the value that's been looked up.

Final main_df

```
Bore      Temperature      Value
4            200            0.5
0.75         500            0.5  
6            200            1.0
2            400            0.5
3            200            0.5
0.75         300            0.5
```

I've tried using pd.merge through various iterations, but cannot seem to get it to work. Is there a better way to do this other than pd.merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with create index by `Bore` column and if necessary convert columns to integers:

```
df['Value'] = (lookup_df.set_index('Bore').rename(columns=int)
                        .lookup(df['Bore'], df['Temperature']))
print (df)
   Bore  Temperature  Value
0  4.00          200    0.5
1  0.75          500    0.5
2  6.00          200    1.0
3  2.00          400    0.5
4  3.00          200    0.5
5  0.75          300    0.5
```

If possible some values missing so first solution failed is possible use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), be free remove `assign` if values are integers in column `Temperature` after `melt`:

```
df1 = (lookup_df.melt('Bore', var_name='Temperature', value_name='Value')
                .assign(Temperature = lambda x: x['Temperature'].astype(int)))
df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df)
   Bore  Temperature  Value
0  4.00          200    0.5
1  0.75          500    0.5
2  6.00          200    1.0
3  2.00          400    0.5
4  3.00          200    0.5
5  0.75          300    0.5
```

Comment: First option seems to give me KeyError: nan, my data listed above isn't my complete data. This error doesn't seem to help me much in determining what might be wrong.

Comment: Second option, I removed the ```assign``` since the values are already integers. I keep getting error ```ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 13, placement implies 1```. Getting this error using following code ```lookup_df2 = (lookup_df.melt('Bore', var_name='Temperature', value_name='Value'))
main_df['Values'] = pd.merge(lookup_df2, how='left')```

Comment: @Stephen can you test `df1 = (lookup_df.melt('Bore', var_name='Temperature', value_name='Value'). dropna(subset=['Temperature'])` instead `df1 = (lookup_df.melt('Bore', var_name='Temperature', value_name='Value')
                .assign(Temperature = lambda x: x['Temperature'].astype(int)))`?

Comment: @jeszrael I was able to get your first DataFrame.melt and Dataframe.merge option to work with my data. I did not end up needing the assign integer part of it, but the merge did get me the results I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using a list comprehension:

```
main_df['value'] = [lookup.loc[lookup['Bore'] == x, str(y)].values[0]
                            for x,y in zip(main_df['Bore'], main_df['Temperature'])]
```

Comment: What is the type of the columns of your lookup df ? If it's not string then you have to replace `str(y)` nu just `y`

Comment: The type for this column is int64. With your suggested change of removing "str", I'm getting the following error ```IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0```

Answer (score 0):

You can stack and merge by Bore+Temperature:

```
main_df = main_df.merge(df_lookup.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['Bore', 'Temperature', 'Value'], axis=1, inplace=False), on=['Bore', 'Temperature'], how='left')
```